# is it possible to shrink preg_replace and str_replace

Tags: php

is it possible to make this more smooth with less line of codes since i have to repeat it for every new box i need to insert it into.

```
$fil_namn = str_replace("5FSE_", "", $fil_url);
$fil_namn = str_replace(".pdf", "", $fil_namn);
$fil_namn = str_replace(".docx", "", $fil_namn);
$fil_namn = str_replace(".doc", "", $fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace("[_]",". ",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. +/','', $fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[AaA]","å",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[AeA]","ä",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[OoO]","ö",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[aAa]","Å",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[aEa]","Ä",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn = preg_replace ("[oOo]","ö",$fil_namn);
$fil_namn= str_replace("."," ", $fil_namn);
```

Comment: `str_replace()` accepts arrays as search and replace parameters: `$fil_namn = str_replace(array('5FSE_', '.pdf', '.docx', '.doc'), '', $fil_namn);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
str_replace(array('5FSE_', '.pdf', '.docx', '.doc'), '', $fill_namn);
```

`str_replace` allows for arrays.

You can also do this:

```
$string = "Hello";

echo str_replace(array("H", "e", "l", "o"), array("A", "l", "e", "x"), $string);
```

This will print out `Aeeex`.

Another method would be to use the `strtr()` function:

```
$string = "[AaA][AeA][OoO][aAa][aEa][oOo]";

$find = array("[AaA]", "[AeA]", "[OoO]", "[aAa]", "[aEa]", "[oOo]");
$replace = array("å", "ä", "ö", "Å", "Ä", "ö");

echo strtr($string, array_combine($find, $replace));
```

This echoes out:

```
åäöÅÄö
```